# How to import submodules and alias them to a variable in ES6

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, module

I want to create a module with some modules of a js file and do something like this:

```
import { CONSTANT01, CONSTANT02 } as selectedConstants from './constants'

console.log(selectedConstants) // output => {CONSTANT01: 'CONSTANT01', CONSTANT02: 'CONSTANT02'}
```

Can this functionality be done?

Comment: [Based on the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), it doesn't look like you can put them into an array like that from just the `import` statement.

Comment: My fault :/ question edited. Output is an object!
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not directly like that, see syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import Perhaps this works for your case `import * as name from "module-name";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't be done like this. Just use a namespace import:

```
import * as selectedConstants from './constants';

console.log(selectedConstants.CONSTANT01) // output => 'CONSTANT01'
console.log(selectedConstants.CONSTANT02) // output => 'CONSTANT02'
```

Comment: So...if I want to join into a JS Object i need to do this:
`import { CONSTANT01, CONSTANT02 } from './constants'`
`const selectedConstants = { CONSTANT01, CONSTANT02 }`
?

Comment: @HemãVidal Yes, you could do that. But what do you need this object for where a namespace does not suffice?

Comment: I need to use afterwards:
`myConsts = {...selectedConstants, ...selectedConst02}`
To join other future constants imports.
To know which kind of constants is.

Comment: That should work with namespace objects as well, unless your module exports more than the *selected* constants. Then you'd need some helper function that would let you pick individual properties.

Comment: OK @Bergi ... Thanks for the time spent and answer!
I understood now this import behavior!
:)